# expected identifier, found `=` when referencing a vector

Tags: rust

In the [Rust official doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html), there is a code sample as:

```
fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);

    let number_list = vec![102, 34, 6000, 89, 54, 2, 43, 8];

    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);
}
```

I was wondering what `&number_list` looks like (is it the same as `&number_list[0]`), so I tried this example:

```
fn reference() {
    let number_list = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let ref = &number_list;
    println!("{}", ref);
}
```

However, I got the error:

```
error: expected identifier, found `=`
   |
   |     let ref = &number_list;
   |             ^ expected identifier
```

Any clues on this?  Why is it not assign-able and gives an error message that doesn't quite make sense (at least for me)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ref` is a [keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/keywords.html)

try:

```
fn reference() {
    let number_list = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let my_variable = &number_list;
    println!("{}", my_variable);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.ref.html) is a Rust keyword.

> `ref` annotates pattern bindings to make them borrow rather than move. It is not a part of the pattern as far as matching is concerned: it does not affect whether a value is matched, only how it is matched.

Answer (score 0):

`ref` is a keyword. Try adding another name to the variable

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `ref` is a keyword in Rust. But if you wanna use it that much, you can use ref pattern:

```rust
fn reference() {
    let number_list = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let ref my_ref = &number_list;
    println!("{:?}", my_ref);
}
```

And no, `&idxable` isn’t `&idxable[0]`, it’s exactly `&idxable`.

You don’t need vectors in this example by the way.